# variable not declared in this scope - Mingw w64

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

I am getting this error in Mingw 64 bit

```
 error: '_controlfp' was not declared in this scope
```

I tried including `float.h` using

```
#include <float.h>
```

This is my statement

```
 uint32_t old;
_controlfp_s(&old, _PC_64, _MCW_PC);
```

However I am still getting this issue. Also i added the path to the include directory of mingw as the first path to search. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition is present in float.h .It seems that mingw64 attempts to look for this definition in float.h  present in `C:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include` however this definition is present in the file 'C:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include'. In order to resolve this issue I copied the definition to the actual source file.